# Python UDP Port Knocker - Not Working

Tags: python, networking, tcp, udp

I want to code a UDP Port Knocker. I have 5 possible UDP ports 2222,3333,4444,5555,6666 and I should knock this ports on a certain IP address, if the knock sequence is correct (e.g. 3333,4444,2222) I can talk to the server via TCP and it will give me an answer. Otherwise no answer and no connection.

Why does my code not work? The 'x' in the code mark places where normally private information are put in - no syntax errors.

```
import socket
import time

UDP_IP = "xxxxx"
TCP_IP = 'xxxxx'
TCP_PORT = 1111

request = "xxx"

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
d = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

def my_range(start, end, step):
    while start <= end:
        yield start
        start += step

for x in my_range(2222, 6666, 1111):
    for y in my_range(2222, 6666, 1111):
        for z in my_range(2222, 6666, 1111):
            print "Port knock: ",x,y,z
            s.sendto(request,(UDP_IP, x))
            s.sendto(request,(UDP_IP, y))
            s.sendto(request,(UDP_IP, z))
            print "Waiting..."
            time.sleep(1)
            try:
                d.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
                print "SUCCESS:",x,y,z
                time.sleep(1)
                data = d.recv(1024)
                print "Servers says: " + data
            except socket.error:
                print "False combination of ports"
                continue
s.close()
d.close()
```

Comment: why do you invent `range` new?

Comment: can you show the server code?

Answer (score 0):

UDP is a stateless protocol. The order of the udp-packages is not guaranteed. E.g. x,y,z can reach the server as y,x,z or any other combination.

Comment: ok, but how do I solve the exercise and send the packets in the correct order?